# Javascript isn't loading when I use wp_enqueue_script, but CSS is when I use wp_enqueue_style

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

functions.php:

```
function filmstarrrr_files() {
    wp_enqueue_script('filmstarrrr-main-script', get_theme_file_uri('/build/script.js'), NULL, '1.0', false);
    wp_enqueue_style('filmstarrrr_main_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/build/index.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('filmstarrrr_google_fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'filmstarrrr_files');
```

style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Filmstarrrr
Author: Filmstarrrr
Version: 1.0
*/
```

index.js:

```
const navBar = document.querySelector('.main-navigation')
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn-5')
const sideBar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
const body = document.querySelector('body')

let lastScroll = 0

function handleScroll() {
    let currentScroll = window.scrollY
    if (currentScroll < lastScroll && lastScroll !== 0) {
        console.log('scrolling up')
        navBar.classList.add('scrollup')
        navBar.classList.remove('scrolldown')
        navBar.classList.remove('top')
    }
    if (currentScroll > lastScroll) {
        console.log("scrolling down")
        navBar.classList.add('scrolldown')
        navBar.classList.remove('scrollup')
        navBar.classList.remove('top')
    }
    if (currentScroll <= 0) {
        console.log('at top')
        navBar.classList.add('top')
        navBar.classList.remove('scrollup')
        navBar.classList.remove('scrolldown')
    }
    lastScroll = currentScroll
} 

function toggleActive() {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle('active')
    sideBar.classList.toggle('sidebaractive')
    body.classList.toggle('lock')
    
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleActive)
```

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
        <nav class="main-navigation">

            <div class="logo">Logo</div>
            <div class="link-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Editorial</li>
                    <li>Personal</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
                <div class="menu-btn-5">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <aside class="sidebar">
                    <nav class="mobile-navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Editorial</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </aside>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </header>
```

footer.php:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
get_header(); 
?>




<?php
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Did some poking around but still can't seem to find the issue. When I open devtools on chrome, I can see the script tag but I notice there isn't an src attribute inside that should point to my js file. I'm quite new to wordpress so don't roast me too hard lol. Thanks.

Comment: how are you testing that the JS doesn't load? Is the `build/script.js` present? What is the value of `get_theme_file_uri('/build/script.js')`? Is this a child theme? Note that using Googles CDN to serve fonts carries some performance penalties, and has regulatory and legal privacy consequences in several countries and states

Comment: @TomJNowell Do you mean "performance benefits"?

Comment: @TomJNowell ```wp_script_is()``` is indicating that my script has been enqueued, but the JS isn't actually working on the webpage for some reason. It isn't a child theme.

Comment: "Isn't loading" is different than "is enqueued but not doing what is expected." I would try enqueueing it to the footer or adding a document ready style condition around it.

Comment: Your code is enqueued in the header, but queries selectors for elements that will not be loaded yet. You should load your script in the footer.

Comment: at a minimum I'd add `console.log('this script has loaded')` to confirm this, likewise just because it's enqueued doesn't mean the URL is correct, that's why I asked what the value of the `get_theme_file_uri` was so we could confirm if it actually found the file and returned a valid URL instead of blank. WebElaine is right too, the JS tries to grab things with `document.querySelector` but never checks if it actually found them and assumes it worked, these are probably mentioned in the error console too

Comment: @Caleb no, I meant penalty. CDNs had an advantage in the old days that sometimes you didn't need to load a resource because another site loaded it and it was already in cache, but modern browsers have separate caches per domain so it will always try to load it at least once for each site, and it can't use HTTP2 multi-stream to do it because it's on a different server so it has to make a new connection. It's also _very_ problematic for visitors from EU countries. All problems that vanish if you host the files yourself, which is what the default themes have started doing

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes I know all that: the use of "but" made me think the first part of the sentence was meant to be a positive.